# What is the meaning of the German surname "Wiesch"?

Tags: germany, surnames

What is the meaning of the German surname "Wiesch"?
I actually want Wieschhaus, but the haus seems easy.

Comment: Hall -- what have you managed to discover so far and where?

Comment: Random guess if this from eastern germany - it could come from Polish Wieś (village).

Answer (score 3):

Hans Bahlow (trans. Edda Gentry): *German Names* under **Wischer** says this is a Westphalian variant of *Wiese* "meadow", and mentions the spelling variant Wiesche.